# Bash, how to print date with a different locale

Tags: bash, date, locale

I am concocting a bash script to generate podcast feed entries.

I need to generate the current time to add to the `pubDate` XML attribute.

The problem is that `date` prints the long time in my machine local language which is spanish:

```
mar ene  5 11:48:17 GMT 2016
```

But I need it in english (not the language of the PC I'm using) and in a slightly different format:

```
Tue, 5 Jan 2016 11:48:17 GMT
```

How can I achieve that other than doing string manipualion to change *"ene"* to *"Jan"*, *"mar"* to *"Tue"*, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the locale you want, before running the *date* command.

```
$ LANG=ru_RU date
вторник,  5 января 2016 г. 11:30:15 (EST)
$ date
Tue Jan  5 11:30:16 EST 2016
```